Is there an add-on for Thunderbird to open an html-Email in a browser?
Is there an for Thunderbird to open an html-Email in a browser?
Is there an add-on, ... anything? If it were, I could use the uBlock Origin and other add-ons in my browser to keep things the way I want, instead of trying to achieve the same things in the thunderbird app.
